# 'PreferenceManager()' is not public in 'android.preference.PreferenceManager'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-preferences, preferences

This line gives me error :-

> preferenceManagers = new PreferenceManager(getApplicationContext());

This error I get :-

> 'PreferenceManager()' is not public in 'android.preference.PreferenceManager'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

This is my .xlm :-

```
package com.dccodes.chugli;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.dccodes.chugli.Adapters.MessagesAdapter;
import com.dccodes.chugli.Models.Message;
import com.dccodes.chugli.databinding.ActivityChatBinding;
import com.dccodes.chugli.utilities.Constants;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityChatBinding binding;
    public PreferenceManager preferenceManagers;
    MessagesAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Message> messages;

    String senderRoom, receiverRoom;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    FirebaseFirestore databases;
    FirebaseStorage storage;

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    String senderUid;
    String receiverUid;
    String token;
    String name;
    private String conversationId = null;
    private List<Message> chatMessage;
    private MessagesAdapter chatAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityChatBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        preferenceManagers = new PreferenceManager(getApplicationContext());
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);



        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Uploading image...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        messages = new ArrayList<>();


        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        String profile = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
        String token = getIntent().getStringExtra("token");

        //Toast.makeText(this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        binding.name.setText(name);
        Glide.with(ChatActivity.this).load(profile)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar)
                .into(binding.profile);

        binding.imageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        receiverUid = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");
        senderUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();

        database.getReference().child("presence").child(receiverUid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()) {
                    String status = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    if(!status.isEmpty()) {
                        if(status.equals("Offline")) {
                            binding.status.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            binding.status.setText(status);
                            binding.status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        senderRoom = senderUid + receiverUid;
        receiverRoom = receiverUid + senderUid;

        adapter = new MessagesAdapter(this, messages, senderRoom, receiverRoom);
        binding.messageViewBox.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        binding.messageViewBox.setAdapter(adapter);

        database.getReference().child("chats")
                .child(senderRoom)
                .child("messages")
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        messages.clear();
                        for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Message message = snapshot1.getValue(Message.class);
                            message.setMessageId(snapshot1.getKey());
                            messages.add(message);
                            binding.messageViewBox.smoothScrollToPosition(Objects.requireNonNull(binding.messageViewBox.getAdapter()).getItemCount());
                        }

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

        binding.sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String messageTxt = binding.messageBox.getText().toString();

                Date date = new Date();
                Message message = new Message(messageTxt, senderUid, date.getTime());
                binding.messageBox.setText("");

                String randomKey = database.getReference().push().getKey();

                HashMap<String, Object> lastMsgObj = new HashMap<>();
                lastMsgObj.put("lastMsg", message.getMessage());
                lastMsgObj.put("lastMsgTime", date.getTime());

                database.getReference().child("chats").child(senderRoom).updateChildren(lastMsgObj);
                database.getReference().child("chats").child(receiverRoom).updateChildren(lastMsgObj);

                database.getReference().child("chats")
                        .child(senderRoom)
                        .child("messages")
                        .child(randomKey)
                        .setValue(message).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                database.getReference().child("chats")
                                        .child(receiverRoom)
                                        .child("messages")
                                        .child(randomKey)
                                        .setValue(message).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                sendNotification(name, message.getMessage(), token);
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        });

            }
        });

        binding.attachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Feature Coming Soon...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                Intent intent = new Intent();
//                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//                intent.setType("image/*");
//                startActivityForResult(intent, 25);
            }
        });
        binding.camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Feature Coming Soon...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                Intent intent = new Intent();
//                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//                intent.setType("image/*");
//                startActivityForResult(intent, 25);
            }
        });

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        binding.messageBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                database.getReference().child("presence").child(senderUid).setValue("typing...");
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                handler.postDelayed(userStoppedTyping,1000);
            }

            Runnable userStoppedTyping = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    database.getReference().child("presence").child(senderUid).setValue("Online");
                }
            };
        });


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

//        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);
//
//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    private void init(){
        preferenceManagers = new PreferenceManager(getApplicationContext());
        chatMessage = new ArrayList<>();
        chatAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(
                chatMessage,
                preferenceManagers.getString()
        )
    }

    void sendNotification(String name, String message, String token) {
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            String url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("title", name);
            data.put("body", message);
            JSONObject notificationData = new JSONObject();
            notificationData.put("notification", data);
            notificationData.put("to",token);

            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, notificationData
                    , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    String key = "Key=AAAAzSjNf6E:APA91bEKDbO2puvbS29Fdu3jxoznS8PG7m_fnXbk3KW04yEDFoX82vJ8NqqvSGghZkhZdowx_B9xS1KGx8EvnVryH4uQdZRRIhqJjQnjR-ie2AgKPM5f8VrDHQ6eGpyDxAi1i9qoWp5h";
                    map.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    map.put("Authorization", key);

                    return map;
                }
            };

            queue.add(request);


        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 25) {
            if(data != null) {
                if(data.getData() != null) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("chats").child(calendar.getTimeInMillis() + "");
                    dialog.show();
                    reference.putFile(selectedImage).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                        String filePath = uri.toString();

                                        String messageTxt = binding.messageBox.getText().toString();

                                        Date date = new Date();
                                        Message message = new Message(messageTxt, senderUid, date.getTime());
                                        message.setMessage("photo");
                                        message.setImageUrl(filePath);
                                        binding.messageBox.setText("");

                                        String randomKey = database.getReference().push().getKey();

                                        HashMap<String, Object> lastMsgObj = new HashMap<>();
                                        lastMsgObj.put("lastMsg", message.getMessage());
                                        lastMsgObj.put("lastMsgTime", date.getTime());

                                        database.getReference().child("chats").child(senderRoom).updateChildren(lastMsgObj);
                                        database.getReference().child("chats").child(receiverRoom).updateChildren(lastMsgObj);

                                        database.getReference().child("chats")
                                                .child(senderRoom)
                                                .child("messages")
                                                .child(randomKey)
                                                .setValue(message).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                        database.getReference().child("chats")
                                                                .child(receiverRoom)
                                                                .child("messages")
                                                                .child(randomKey)
                                                                .setValue(message).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                                                    }
                                                                });
                                                    }
                                                });

                                        //Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, filePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        String currentId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
        database.getReference().child("presence").child(currentId).setValue("Online");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        String currentId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
        database.getReference().child("presence").child(currentId).setValue("Offline");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        finish();
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    private void checkForConversation(){
        if(chatMessage.size() != 0){
                checkForConversationRemotely(
                        preferenceManagers.getString()
                );
        }
    }

    private void checkForConversationRemotely(String senderUid, String receiverUid){
        databases.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CONVERSATIONS)
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID, senderUid)
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID, receiverUid)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(conversationOnCompleteListener);
    }

    private final OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot> conversationOnCompleteListener = task -> {
        if(task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult()!=null && task.getResult().getDocuments().size() > 0){
            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(0);
            conversationId = documentSnapshot.getId();
        }
    };
}
```

I don't know why I get this error...! Please can anyone help me out of this error ? The following sentences are underlined with red in my code :-

> #line85
> preferenceManagers = new PreferenceManager(getApplicationContext());

> #line271
> preferenceManagers = new PreferenceManager(getApplicationContext());

> #line275
> preferenceManagers.getString()

> #line423
> preferenceManagers.getString()

Please can anyone help me out in this problem ? I will be very thankful to you...❤️❤️❤️

Answer (score 0):

I think the constructor `PreferenceManager(context)` is private in it package so you can not use it in your code. May you can try my solution here:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    void init(context: Context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCE_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    Boolean getString(String: key, String: defaultValue) {
        sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
    }

    void putString(String: key, Boolean: saveValue) {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(key, saveValue).apply();
    }
```

Comment: Can u edit my whole .xlm file because I am unable to fix it.....?