# PreferenceManager(context) is private in the pacakage

Tags: android, android-studio, android-preferences, preferences

`PreferenceManager(context)` is private in the package and I need to convert it to `public` to use. I don't know how to do so. **So, can anyone help me ?**

Comment: you can't do this. could you please elaborate why you want to do this? there is a better way/aproach for shure

Comment: I need to do this because I am using this code from youtube and this worked in his pc but it is not wokring in mine, If this is impossible then help me in this :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73358442/preferencemanager-is-not-public-in-android-preference-preferencemanager

Comment: just read [THIS](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) doc, don't rely on some random tutorials... learn, don't just copy...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have an issue, you should post the actual code that's causing it.

But specifically with PreferenceManager, you can't invoke it the way you posted. If you want to instantiate it, you would need to do something like this:

```
String mPrefManager = mContext.getPreferenceManager()
```

where `mContext` would be the actual Context that you're trying to use